# Problem with publishing rtmp stream to FMS with librtmp

Tags: rtmp, flash-media-server

I'm trying to get video from the webcam and get it encoded and then publish the stream to FMS. and now I'am having a problem when I try to publish RTMP stream to the FMS with librtmp.
My code:

```
char uri[]="rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/bolton";
r= RTMP_Alloc();
RTMP_Init(r);   
RTMP_SetupURL(r, (char*)uri);
r->Link.lFlags |= RTMP_LF_LIVE;
r->Link.lFlags |= RTMP_LF_BUFX;
RTMP_EnableWrite(r);
//RTMP_SetBufferMS(r, bufferTime);
RTMP_Connect(r, NULL);
RTMP_ConnectStream(r,0);
```

And log:

```
DEBUG: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
DEBUG: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
DEBUG: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
DEBUG: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
DEBUG: HandShake: Handshaking finished....
DEBUG: RTMP_Connect1, handshaked
DEBUG2: RTMP_SendPacket: fd=768, size=85
DEBUG2:   0000:  03 00 00 00 00 00 55 14  00 00 00 00               ......U.....      
DEBUG2:   0000:  02 00 07 63 6f 6e 6e 65  63 74 00 3f f0 00 00 00   ...connect.?....  
DEBUG2:   0010:  00 00 00 03 00 03 61 70  70 02 00 04 6c 69 76 65   ......app...live  
DEBUG2:   0020:  00 04 74 79 70 65 02 00  0a 6e 6f 6e 70 72 69 76   ..type...nonpriv  
DEBUG2:   0030:  61 74 65 00 05 74 63 55  72 6c 02 00 15 72 74 6d   ate..tcUrl...rtm  
DEBUG2:   0040:  70 3a 2f 2f 31 32 37 2e  30 2e 30 2e 31 2f 6c 69   p://127.0.0.1/li  
DEBUG2:   0050:  76 65 00 00 09                                     ve...             
DEBUG: Invoking connect
DEBUG2: RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=768
ERROR: RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header
DEBUG2: RTMP_SendPacket: fd=-1, size=307
```

It seems that `RTMP_connect` connected correctly, but failes in the function `RTMP_ConnectStream`, I'm not familiar with the rtmp connect sequence, and it's killing me.

What should I do to find the problems, Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm dealing with the same problem, but using librtmp with ffmpeg.  If you look in the function RTMP_ReadPacket(), you'll see the error is thrown when trying to read the packet header with the method ReadN():

```
int
RTMP_ReadPacket(RTMP *r, RTMPPacket *packet)
{
    uint8_t hbuf[RTMP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE] = { 0 };
    char *header = (char *)hbuf;
    int nSize, hSize, nToRead, nChunk;
    int didAlloc = FALSE;

    RTMP_Log(RTMP_LOGDEBUG2, "%s: fd=%d", __FUNCTION__, r->m_sb.sb_socket);

    if (ReadN(r, (char *)hbuf, 1) == 0)
    {
        RTMP_Log(RTMP_LOGERROR, "%s, failed to read RTMP packet header", __FUNCTION__);
        return FALSE;
    }
```

That error only throws if the ReadN returns a 0.  I haven't figured out on my end why that's happening yet, though.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed the problem here, and I think I might have found what was wrong though I am not sure. The method works when I replace the lib OpenSSL to another version that's specifically built for win32. Thank you all the same:)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in the Visual studio.
It turned out that in the debug mode,librtmp set some handshake value 0 instead of generating random data.

```
//handshake.h
  /* generate random data */
#ifdef _DEBUG
  memset(serversig+8, 0, RTMP_SIG_SIZE-8);
#else
  ip = (int32_t *)(serversig+8);
  for (i = 2; i < RTMP_SIG_SIZE/4; i++)
    *ip++ = rand();
#endif
```

Just make sure generating random data.